# Issue with wireless Broadcom 4360 PCI-ID 14e4:43a0

Tags: linux, debian, wifi, network-interface

After looking through many forums, both here and in the Ubuntu/Debian communities, I still cannot connect to wireless. Here is my situation:

-Dual-booting Mac OS Sierra with Debian Jessie
-Had to adjust grub for display by setting acpi=off
-Installed and removed several different packages.
Removed: bcmwl-kernel-source (Reinstalled as well in the end)
Added to deb sources to /etc/apt/sources.list:

```
deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian jessie main non-free
deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian jessie main contrib non-free
```

Installed the following packages:

```
apt-get install broadcom-sta-dkms firmware-linux firmware-linux-free firmware-linux-nonfree firmware-brcm80211 firmware-b43-installer fimware-b43legacy-installer
```

Added to /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf:

```
blacklist brcmsmac
blacklist bcma
blacklist b43
blacklist b44
blacklist ssb
```

Rebooted and no change. Interface showed up only after the broadcom-sta-dkms installed. I tried uninstalling and installing broadcom-sta-common instead but I lost it doing that so switched packages back.

Finally, ran

```
modprobe wl
```

Behavior: I tried with SSID broadcast and without. It doesn't matter what network I connect to, even if there is no authentication required. It can see the networks, even the networks that aren't broadcasting (Sees signal strength), but NEVER connects. I used the netinstall and I heard someone using the full livecd made an install and it worked, but I just want to find the right drivers and be done with it.

Comment: Install a new kernel from backports e,g : the `4.8`

Answer (score 1):

I finally got it working.

Downloaded and installed the Stretch distro netinstall with firmware. After doing that, my display issue needed no fixing. However, even after installing the default dkms package, I still got the same error with `wl` module.

Then, I went directly to the Debian website and downloaded the `.deb` package from stretch, and installed it. Sure enough, it worked after that! The only issue I have now is sometimes when I put the computer to sleep, after waking it up I have to manual reconnect to the wireless network I was on. May bring that part to a different thread, but for now my biggest concern is solved.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install a new kernel from backports to solve the wifi issue :

Edit your `sources.list`

```
apt edit-sources
```

add the following line:

```
deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main contrib non-free
```

Save and update your system then install a new kernel e,g:

```
apt update
apt-get -t jessie-backports install linux-image-4.7.0-0.bpo.1-amd64
apt-get -t jessie-backports install linux-headers-4.7.0-0.bpo.1-amd64
```

**edit**

Install `linux-base` from backports:

```
 apt-get -t jessie-backports install linux-base
```

Reboot and reinstall `broadcom-sta-dkms` :

```
apt-get remove broadcom-sta-dkms bcmwl-kernel-source firmware-brcm80211 firmware-b43-installer fimware-b43legacy-installer

apt-get install dkms build-essential
apt-get -t jessie-backports install broadcom-sta-dkms broadcom-sta-source broadcom-sta-common
```

and reload the `wl` module:

```
rmmod wl && modprobe wl
```

Comment: I got down to installing the image package and got the following:
`The following packages have unmet dependencies:
linux-image-4.7.0-0.bpo.1-amd64 : Depends : linux-base(<= 4.3~) but 3.5 is to be installed.
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages`
Not sure if I should remove linux-base :O

Comment: Ok so I tried the above and let me say firstly this definitely fixed the super tiny icons on my desktop, and I no longer have to add additional options into grub2. Yay! :D. However, it appears the wireless card isn't even showing up anymore, and I uninstalled bcmwl-kernel-source, and attempted to reinstall, but I get the below:
`
Package bcmwl-kernel-source is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

Comment: Also, wl doesn't work either:
`modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:816 kmod_module_insert_module() could not find module by name='wl'
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'wl': Function not implemented
modprobe: ERROR: ../libkmod/libkmod-module.c:960 command_do() Error running install command for wl
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'wl': Operation not permitted
`

Comment: It is installed. I even reinstalled. Still no dice :(

Comment: What is the output of `insmod wl.ko` ?

Comment: Two issues:

`apt-get install broadcom-sta-dkms 

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 broadcom-sta-dkms : Breaks: broadcom-sta-common but 6.30.223.248-3 is to be installed
                     Breaks: broadcom-sta-source but 6.30.223.248-3 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.`

`apt-get install broadcom-sta-dkms
Module build for the currently running kernel was skipped since the
kernel source for this kernel does not seem to be installed.`

Comment: Is it wl *dot* ko?

`This is what I get:insmod: ERROR: could not load module wl.ko: No such file or directory`

Comment: run , `apt-get upgrade && apt-get dist-upgrade` then `apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)` and `apt-get -f install` .

Comment: Output:
apt-get upgrade
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
apt-get dist-upgrade
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package linux-headers-4.7.0-0.bpo.1-amd64
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'linux-headers-4.7.0-0.bpo.1-amd64'

apt-get -f install
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

Comment: `apt-get -t jessie-backports install broadcom-sta-dkms broadcom-sta-source broadcom-sta-common`

Comment: Yeah I just thought about that lol. Looks like the upgrades are flowing now. I'll be back momentarily. Still can't get the linux-headers package though, even in backports.

Comment: So I did backports for upgrade and the three Broadcom packages and it worked, however rebooting I still get the same error with modprobe wl command. Doing dist-upgrade for backports

Comment: I am not sure what to do at this point. It seems to be related to wl so I uninstalled and reinstalled with backports option, but still same error. Going to go sniff around.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52099/discussion-between-ofwolfandman-and-gad3r).